# Plotly: Chart with errors

Tags: python, charts, plotly

I have created the most basic `plotly` chart.

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.line(
    slices,
    x=slices['quote_datetime'], 
    y=slices['Close'])

fig.show()
```

However, the result seems to have an error. There are no null/na values in the underlying data.

Example chart with error:

[image: Example chart with error]

Comment: This is a common problem – have you tried sorting `slices` by `'quote_datetime'` ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DerekO many thx. This has solved it

Comment: @khrizz great! i'll add my comment as an answer – that way if you accept it, others who need help can find the answer more easily

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the datetimes aren't sorted. You can sort `slices` by `quote_datetime` using:

```
slices.sort_values(by='quote_datetime', inplace=True)
```